# Group states into two buckets ( west and central) in R

Tags: r

I have a large file with all Usa state abbreviated. I want to put these states in 2 different buckets like CA,AR,NV,UT in west..TX,KS,IA in central...and then i want to summarise how much sale is comming from each bucket.Just started using R. so what is best way to do this? I have my data in excel sheet. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi, please provide some sample data to help answer the question. The best way to get an answer is to provide a reproducible example; see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

there are a ton of ways to approach this in r, I'd recommend using dplyr for it. That said, in order to get actual answers to your problem, you're going to have to do at least the initial steps, such as loading the data, yourself and then provide some relevant details of what you've tried and what isn't working.

stackoverflow is a great resource, and people are happy to help, but when it looks like you're trying to get someone else to do all the work for you you're going to get down-voted and negative responses.

here are some guides to both:

[dplyr](http://www.datacarpentry.org/R-genomics/04-dplyr.html)

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)